# help with custom positioning error messages

Tags: jquery, positioning, message, validation

I'm playing with the great Bassistance jQuery Validator and am stuck at a point
The idea is simple: I have lot of this markup (I semplify, but the idea is that after each  there could be something else, i.e. a word, an icon, etc... that is "inline" with the corresponding):

```
<ol>
<li><input type="text" id="width" size="3"></input> px</li>
<li><input type="text" id="height" size="3"></input> px</li>
<li><input type="text" id="thumb" size="3"></input> px</li>
</ol>
```

Well, the Validator "forces" the error messages to appear just after the , so I get something like:

> [input] "insert a number here" px
>
> [input] "insert a number here" px
>
> [input] "insert a number here" px

In other words, the error messages "split" the natural flow of the line

The best would be to put the error message on a line after the +following element, so:

> [input] px
>
> "insert a number here"
>
> [input] px
>
> "insert a number here"
>
> [input] px
>
> "insert a number here"

But there's no way to reach this

Wrapping the  and the following element in a  has no effect, since the error message alway go after the  and not after the wrapper div

The error container demo (http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/errorcontainer-demo.html) does not match my needs since it wraps ALL errors in a single div - but the idea of showing the error NOT close to the  is nice

Please, can you help? Is there a solution for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you want to set the errorPlacement argument. [There's a demo here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) (search for errorPlacement).

Answer (score 0):

But what if he want a different placement only for one field ?


Let say he have:

**Name:** [textbox] *error here* (required)

**Email:** [textbox] *error here* (required + email)


**Interests:** (at least 2 checked)

*error here*

[checkbox] Foo

[checkbox] Bar

[checkbox] Bla

[checkbox] Blu